# Somar saldo financeiro com Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Estou tentando desenvolver um programa de controle de vendas em Java, porém estou com um problema na hora de programar o saldo da Jtable.

Conforme vocês podem ver na imagem abaixo, o saldo está sendo atualizado por linha. No entanto, visto que eu declarei o saldo inicial igual a 0 eu preciso que ele some com o valor total da primeira linha para atualizar o saldo da primeira linha, depois pegar o saldo da primeira linha e somar com o valor total da segunda linha e atualizar o saldo da segunda linha(passando a ser um saldo acumulativo). Como eu faço isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Classe Venda

```
public class Venda { 

private String pontoVenda;
private String cliente;
private String produto;
private String tipo;
private int quantidade;
private float valor;
public float valorTotal;
public double saldo = 0;

public String getPontoVenda() {

    return pontoVenda;
}

public void setPontoVenda(String pontoVenda) {
    this.pontoVenda = pontoVenda;
}

public String getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(String cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public String getProduto() {
    return produto;
}

public void setProduto(String produto) {
    this.produto = produto;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public int getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
}

public void setQuantidade(int quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
}

public float getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(float valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}

public float getValorTotal() {
    return valorTotal;
}

public void setValorTotal(float valorTotal) {
    this.valorTotal = valor * quantidade;
}

public double getSaldo() {
    return saldo;
}

public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
    this.saldo = saldo + valorTotal;
}

}
```

---

```
public class ProdutoTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private List<Venda> dados = new ArrayList<>();
private String[] colunas = {"Ponto de Venda", "Cliente", "Produto", "Tipo", 
    "Quantidade" ,"Valor(unid.)", "Valor Total", "Saldo"};

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column){
    return colunas[column];
}
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return dados.size();      
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return colunas.length;
}


@Override
public Object getValueAt(int linha, int coluna) {
    switch (coluna){
        case 0:
            return dados.get(linha).getPontoVenda();
        case 1:
            return dados.get(linha).getCliente();
        case 2:
            return dados.get(linha).getProduto();
        case 3:
            return dados.get(linha).getTipo();
        case 4:
            return dados.get(linha).getQuantidade();
        case 5:
            return dados.get(linha).getValor();
        case 6:
            return dados.get(linha).getValorTotal();
        case 7:
            return dados.get(linha).getSaldo();
    }
    return null;

}
```

---

```
    private void btnSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Venda p = new Venda();
    p.setPontoVenda(itemPonto.getSelectedItem().toString());
    p.setCliente(itemCliente.getSelectedItem().toString());
    p.setProduto(itemProduto.getSelectedItem().toString());
    p.setTipo(itemTipo.getSelectedItem().toString());
    p.setQuantidade(Integer.parseInt(txtQuantidade.getText()));
    p.setValor(Float.parseFloat(txtValor.getText()));
    p.setValorTotal(p.valorTotal); 
    p.setSaldo(p.saldo);

    tableModel.addRow(p);
```

Comment: Se saldo se refere, pelo que entendi, ao total de varios produtos, porque você está guardando em um produto? O erro da lógica começa ai, saldo não deveria ser um campo de produto. Dica, remova essa coluna saldo da tabela, e da classe Produto, coloque como um Textfield em baixo dela, e atualize-o conforme for adicionado novos produtos, vai ficar bem mais facil assim.

Comment: Fala Diego! Obrigado pelo retorno! Então a class produto na verdade é a venda. Eu que coloquei no nome produto, mas na verdade é a venda. Por isso que eu coloquei saldo dentro dela. Se eu mudar o produto no combobox a venda vai ser inserida na Jtable de qualquer forma.

Comment: Mas não faz sentido a classe produto ser vendas. São duas coisas completamente diferentes. Se quer facilitar e não colocar gambiarras no seu programa, sugiro criar uma entidade venda na sua tabela, e criar um id para cada venda, e deixar produtos apenas para cada produto e suas caracteristicas, vinculando os dois.

Comment: E não é necessário salvar total nesse modelo que sugeri, apenas seguir uma formula simples: `vendaTotal = vendaTotal + produto.preco x quantidadeComprada` isso para todos os produtos vinculados aquela venda.

Comment: Oi Diego, então eu mudei o nome da classe lá para ficar mais fácil de entender. Quando eu insiro os dados não é de um produto e sim de uma venda. Mesmo assim você acha que o saldo deve ficar fora? Desculpa se eu estiver falando alguma coisa idiota, mas eu estou no inicio mesmo então ainda fico muito confuso

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta explicando uma solução mais tranquila de lhe dar.

Answer (score 2):

A dica que lhe dou é remover esta coluna e este campo de `Venda`, não faz muito sentido ficar atualizando o saldo a cada linha da compra, quando você só precisa de um campo sendo atualizado a cada produto adicionado a venda.

Como alternativa a esta coluna, você poderia adicionar um  `JTextFied`(ou JLabel, fica a sua escolha) logo abaixo da tabela, e atualizar este campo com o total, fazendo um método mais ou menos assim:

```
public void atualizarSaldo(){

    float saldo, produtoValor;
    int produtoQuantidade;

        for(int i = 0; i < suaTable.getRowCount(); i++){

            produtoValor = suaTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 5);
            produtoQuantidade = suaTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 4);

            saldo += (produtoQuantidade * produtoValor);

        }

    campoSaldo.setText(saldo);

}
```

Basta chamar este método no mesmo lugar que você adiciona um novo produto a sua tabela.

Comment: Obrigado Diego,eu vou tentar fazer isso agora! Eu queria colocar o saldo a cada linha,pois eu ainda vou adicionar uma coluna de Data e queria ver pela data e também por uma questão de layout do software como se fosse um extrato bancário

Comment: @FelipePaifer então há um grave erro no layout do seu programa. Perceba que cada venda só permite um produto, faz sentido isso? Ao menos se venda armazenasse uma lista de produtos, daria até pra sugerir algo no proprio tablemodel. Da forma que está, não irá dar certo sem gambiarras que resolverão este problema e criarão inumeros outros no futuro.

Comment: @FelipePaifer A resposta lhe ajudou? Se sim, você pode marcá-la como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda da resposta :)