# Calcular media de tempo em Java

Tags: java, swing

Gostaria de saber como faço para calcular a media de tempo através de uma tabela em java?

O que eu quero fazer é que quando o usuário  pesquisar um cliente, ira aparecer na tabela apenas as informações do chamado do cliente junto com o tempo do chamado, apos isso ele ira clicar no botão "Gerar Relatório" e ira aparecer no campo de texto a media de tempo todos os chamados.

Já fiz as pesquisa, só falta realizar a media de tempo. Segue o que ja consegui fazer:

> Relatorio.java

```
   /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package view;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import model.bean.Produto;
import model.dao.ProdutoDAO;

/**
 *
 * @author Samuelson
 */
public class Relatorio extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ViewJTable
     */
    public Relatorio() {
        initComponents();
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jTProdutos.getModel();
        jTProdutos.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(modelo));

        readJTable();

    }

    public void readJTable() {

        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jTProdutos.getModel();
        modelo.setNumRows(0);
        ProdutoDAO pdao = new ProdutoDAO();

        for (Produto p : pdao.read()) {

            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
                p.getId(),

                p.getCliente(),
                p.getPreco(),
                p.getDescricao(),

                p.getQtd(),                    
                p.getStatus()
            });

        }

    }
    public void readJTableForDesc(String desc) {

        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jTProdutos.getModel();
        modelo.setNumRows(0);
        ProdutoDAO pdao = new ProdutoDAO();

        for (Produto p : pdao.readForDesc(desc)) {

            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
               p.getId(),

                p.getCliente(),
                p.getPreco(),
                p.getDescricao(),

                p.getQtd(),                    
                p.getStatus()
            });

        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        txtBuscaDesc = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTProdutos = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton4.setText("Buscar");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTProdutos.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "ID", "Cliente", "Problema", "Descricao", "Tempo", "STATUS"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false, false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jTProdutos.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jTProdutosMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jTProdutos.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTProdutosKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTProdutos);

        jButton1.setText("Chamados");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Cadastrar Chamado");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Relatorio");

        jLabel1.setText("Relatorio");

        jButton5.setText("Cadastrar clientes");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setText("Gerar relatorio");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(291, 291, 291))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 68, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton6)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 425, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(txtBuscaDesc)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton4))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtBuscaDesc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 248, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton5)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(56, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 248, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        readJTableForDesc(txtBuscaDesc.getText());

    }                                        

    private void jTProdutosKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        if (jTProdutos.getSelectedRow() != -1) {


        }
    }                                      

    private void jTProdutosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        if (jTProdutos.getSelectedRow() != -1) {


        }
    }                                       

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        this.dispose();
        Relatorio obj = new Relatorio();
        obj.setVisible(true); 
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      this.dispose();
        CadastrarChamado obj = new CadastrarChamado();
        obj.setVisible(true); 
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 this.dispose();
        CadastrarClientes obj = new CadastrarClientes();
        obj.setVisible(true);         // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Relatorio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Relatorio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Relatorio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Relatorio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Relatorio().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTProdutos;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtBuscaDesc;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

[image: jav]

Comment: q medida de tempo e essa ai? Numero inteiro normal? Não é no formato `HH:mm`?

Comment: Olá, eu estou começando em java agora, eu só queria saber como faço para calcular a media de tempo da coluna "tempo" de acordo com o cliente.

Comment: Eu perguntei se a coluna TEMPO é do tipo inteiro normal.

Comment: Primeiro entenda que MÉDIA. 
média é o resultado da soma, dividido pela quantidade de parcelas.
Suponhamos que temos A SOMA: 10+20+30=60 
MEDIA = 60/3 - o valor médio é :  20 Ja tem ciencia disso?

Comment: Não, ta tudo como string

Comment: @Marck porque nao mudou a coluna pra inteiro, ja q ela so vai comportar numeros? Vai da mais trabalho convertendo pra somar do que mudando a coluna pra int.

Answer (score 1):

Se a coluna `Tempo` for tipo inteiro normal(o que não faz muito sentido pra uma coluna de tempo), basta seguir a mesma idéia [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206162/28595), onde você irá varrer todas as células da coluna citada, somar e dividir pelo total de colunas:

```
float soma = 0f;
int rowCount = suaTable.getRowCount();

for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){

    soma += suaTable.getModel().getValue(i, 4);

}

seuTexField.setText(soma/rowCount);
```

Comment: Esse código eu coloco em qual parte do meu código?

Comment: @Marck voce precisa adapta-lo, ele é apenas demonstrativo. Você irá invocar na ação do botão.